# Converting json into csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a json file which I read and try to convert into csv

```
"items": [
      "id": "CITY",
      "info": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "type": "box",
          "attributes": {
            "category": "Tree",
          },
          "group": 0,
          "z_order": 0,
          "box": [
            223.54,
            1.13,
            27.3,
            2.13
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 0,
          "type": "box",
          "attributes": {
            "category": "Building",
          },
          "group": 0,
          "z_order": 0,
          "bbox": [
            9.91,
            64.21,
            313.1,
            13.09
          ]
        }
      ],
      "attr": {
        "frame": 47
      },
      "image": {
        "size": [
          3024,
          4032
        ],
        "path": "photo2.jpeg"
      }
    },
```

Here's a snippet of my code , I tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data["items"])
```

and output is it creates these tables:

```
 id,info,attr.frame,image.size,image.path
```

I would've liked to have more columns outputs like

```
info.attributes, info.box, info.image
```

Any help? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not the most beautiful solution but it's working, it could help to find a better solution:

```
df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(data))['items'].apply(pd.Series).explode('info')
df['image.size'] = df['image'].apply(pd.Series)['size']
df['image.path'] = df['image'].apply(pd.Series)['path']
df['attr.frame'] = df['attr'].apply(pd.Series)['frame']
df['info.id'] = df['info'].apply(pd.Series)['id']
df['info.type'] = df['info'].apply(pd.Series)['type']
df['info.attributes'] = df['info'].apply(pd.Series)['attributes']
df['info.attributes.category'] = df['info.attributes'].apply(pd.Series)['category']
df['info.group'] = df['info'].apply(pd.Series)['group']
df['info.z_order'] = df['info'].apply(pd.Series)['z_order']
df['info.box'] = df['info'].apply(pd.Series)['box']
df.drop(columns=['info', 'attr', 'info.attributes', 'image'], inplace=True)
```

The first line is to create one row by element in info, the last line to remove the column with dictionnary inside to avoid redundant information.

Comment: hey thanks for answer! byt got `id, type,attributes` etc KeyErrors
with image.size , image.path, attr.frame - fine

Comment: even 1st line got this error `ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.`

Comment: What is the type of data for you ? I suppose it was a dictionnary, if it is a string, you can replace pd.read_json(json.dumps(data)) by pd.read_json(data) at the first line.